# Command Prompt as Admin with %username% variables of actual user

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

Trying to set some firewall rules for a machine on a domain. It requires admin permissions through cmd prompt to set them, however I want to use the %username% variable as the command requires a specific folder stored in the logged in users appdata to be allowed.

Is there anyway to work around this?

As when launching cmd prompt as admin, it uses my admin username in %username% rather than the logged in user and I'm hoping to automate this. Needs to be done through cmd/powershell/batch.

Comment: You say cmd, but say need it done through powershell or cmd? So can you post the code where you're having trouble with this. You can just query the user logged in instead of using `%username` which will be the user running the script.

Comment: You could do one of the following: 1) Set up the firewall rule for every profile folder on the system and forget trying to figure out who just logged on. 2) Have a log on script that runs to output the current user into a text file. Then read that text file with your admin script. 3) Read the event log to find the logged on user since you will be running elevated anyway. 4) Post the code you are trying so people can help narrow down where your issues are.

Comment: Have managed to resolve it myself. I've managed to save the variable to a file, and call that file into a second command prompt session elevated as admin and use a different variable.

First:
`echo %USERNAME%>C:\dir\file.txt`

Second:
`cd C:\dir\
set /P uname=<uname.txt
echo %uname%`

Answer (score 1):

Have managed to resolve it myself. I've managed to save the variable to a file, and call that file into a second command prompt session elevated as admin and use a different variable.

First:

```
echo %USERNAME%>C:\dir\file.txt
```

Second:

```
cd C:\dir\ 
set /P uname=<uname.txt 
echo %uname%
```